# Comprobar si una matriz cuadrada es simétrica en C

Tags: c

Me estoy iniciando en la programación y tengo que hacer un trabajo para la facultad, tengo problemas ya que inicie tarde el ciclo de clases quisiera saber si me podrían ayudar con esto. El ejercicio en cuestión es éste:

> Realice un programa en lenguaje `C` que compruebe si una matriz cuadrada de 3x3 dada es una matriz simétrica. Mostrar la matriz mediante la representación gráfica propia de las matrices.

Éste es el código que llevo hecho hasta el momento:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){
int matriz[3][3];
bool sim = true;
printf("Ingrese valores para la matriz 3x3\n ");    

 for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++ ){
        printf("Elemento  [%d | %d] : ", i,j);
        scanf(" %d",&matriz[i][j]);
}   
 }
     printf("Elementos almacenados en la matriz: \n\n");

 for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        printf(" %d ", matriz[i][j]);

        if(matriz[i][j] != matriz[j][i]){
        sim = false;
        i = 3;
        break;
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
}
if(sim==true)
    printf("La matriz es simetrica");
else
    printf("La matriz NO es simetrica ");

getch();
return 0;
}
```

El problema es que no me muestra la matriz completa. ¿Por qué puede ser? ¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Comment: Preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo ([fuente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). Por favor, edita tu pregunta para añadir lo que lleves hecho hasta el momento y los problemas que te estés encontrando

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y añade el código que lleves, así como el resultado que recibes y el que esperas.

Comment: Ya lo edite, gracias

Comment: Si lo que quieres es que se muestre la matriz completa, entonces lo que deberías hacer es eliminar `i = 3;
        break;` que es lo que hace que el bucle se rompa antes de tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se para que le pones tantas librerias si lo unico que nesesitas son metodos de entrada/salida, bueno te recomiendo leer [El lenguaje de programacion C](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131103628) te va a ayudar un monton para entenderlo todo, en cuanto a tu programa, estas bien, al menos te diste cuenta del `if(matriz[i][j] != matriz[j][i])` que es basicamente la linea mas importante del programa, solo que tienes todo desordenado.

Mira aqui te lo ordeno..

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int matriz[3][3];
    int numero, simetria;
    printf("Ingrese elementos de matriz:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &numero);
            matriz[i][j] = numero;
        }
    }

    //para comprobar si es simetrica
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (matriz[i][j] != matriz[j][i]) 
                simetria = 0;
            simetria = 1;
        }
    }

    //imprimimos si es simetrica o no
    if (simetria == 1) {
        printf("La matriz es simetrica!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("la matriz no es simetrica\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Igual esa matriz esta mal, yo lo hice así

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int matriz[100][100],fico,cont=0;

    cout<<"Ingrese le numero de filas y columnas: "; cin>>fico;


    for(int i=0;i<fico;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<fico;j++){
            cout<<"Numero? ";
            cin>>matriz[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<fico;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<fico;j++){
            cout<<matriz[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<fico;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<fico;j++){
            if(matriz[i][j]==matriz[j][i]){
                    cont++;
            }
        }
    }

    if(cont==fico*fico){
        cout<<"Es correcto";
    }


    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Y si al usuario le da por poner más de 100 filas? Además, nota que la pregunta está etiquetada como C, por lo que no puedes usar `cin` ni `cout`... ni por supuesto `<iostream>`